# Explicitly cast from generic type to an object of its type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I want to create a `Validatable<T>` class which is similar in concept to `Nullable<T>`. I have an `IValidatable` interface used by many types, but if a type doesn't already implement this interface, I want to make it easy to put a wrapper around it and then use that wrapper to store validations errors.

I want to be able to cast back to the wrapped object, but the cast is failing even though I have an explicit operator set (although actually I'd prefer an implicit operator). Here's the definitions:

```
    public interface IValidatable
    {
        bool IsValid { get; }
        void Validate();
        // (more validation-related methods here...)
    }

    public class Validatable<T> : IValidatable
        where T : class
    {
        public Validatable(T obj)
        {
            Object = obj;
        }

        public T Object { get; private set; }

        public bool IsValid { get; set; }

        public void Validate()
        {

        }

        public static implicit operator Validatable<T>(T other)
        {
            return new Validatable<T>(other);
        }

        public static explicit operator T(Validatable<T> other)
        {
            return other.Object;
        }

    }

    public static class Validatable
    {
        public static IValidatable AsValidatable<T>(T obj)
            where T: class
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return null;

            var already = obj as IValidatable;

            return already ?? new Validatable<T>(obj);
        }
    }

    public class Person // not IValidatable
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

But then if I try:

```
    public void ConversionTest()
    {
        var person = new Person { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Smith" };

        var validatable = Validatable.AsValidatable(person);

        var cast = (Person)validatable; // FAILS here with InvalidCastException
    }
```

Why is casting back to Person failing with an InvalidCastException?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generic explicit cast failure C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934134/generic-explicit-cast-failure-c-sharp)

Comment: I'd vote for leaving it open since this question also involves how Nullable<T> can support this.

Comment: @erikkallen: Is `Nullable` not a special case in the language spec/compiler though?

Comment: @AndreyAkinshin I viewed that question and many others dealing with casting generic types but I don't believe any of them deal with exactly this issue, as the use of the `IValidatable` interface seems to be what tripped me up here.

Comment: Can't you expose the original object on Validatable?  Something like `validatable.GetUnderlying<Person>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you spell out the types explicitly, the problem becomes obvious:

```
public void ConversionTest()
{
    Personperson = new Person { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Smith" };

    IValidatable validatable = Validatable.AsValidatable(person);

    Person cast = (Person)validatable; // FAILS here with InvalidCastException
}
```

Since `validatable` has the interface type, the conversion operator (declared in the `Validatable<T>`) cannot be applied.

`Nullable<T>` has special runtime support to enable this scenario.

Comment: Well I guess the "special runtime support to enable this scenario" is what was confusing me a bit here, thanks for clarifying that. BTW the compiler's message was "Unable to cast object of type 'Validatable`1[Person]' to type 'Person'". So that seems really confusing here; it should be "Unable to cast object of type 'IValidatable' to type 'Person'" instead. Anyway, accepting this since I think it's the clearest answer, thanks.

Comment: It is not the compiler that gives you the error message but the runtime. The special support I was talking about is that when the runtime boxes a Nullable<T>, it will be boxed as either null or the underlying value.

Answer (score 3):

A `Validatable.AsValidatable` returns `IValidatable`, not `Validatable<T>`, and there's no cast for that. Obviously there's no guarantee that an instance of `IValidatable` is also an instance of `Validatable<T>`.

It does work if you do if you ignore `AsValidatable` and use your cast operator in the other direction though nicely:

```
    public static void ConversionTest()
    {
        var person = new Person { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Smith" };

        var validatable = (Validatable<Person>)person;           

        var cast = (Person)validatable; // FAILS here with InvalidCastException
    }
```

For `Nullable` they cheated - its a special case.

Comment: This is not technically wrong, but the OP has defined a conversion operator to support it, so the question is more why that conversion operator does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. To answer your question, I did consider something along those lines, but this is just a contrived example to demonstrate the issue; in my actual code I don't want to have to distinguish between a type that actually implements `IValidatable` and one what is wrapped by `Validatable<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `IValidatable` is not convertible to `Person` -- only `Validatable` is. The compiler will insert a simple cast and cannot invoke your operator because it doesn't know the concrete type.

As an alternative to what you're trying to do, you could go the route of `Comparer` and `IComparable`: implement `Validator.Default` that gives a `Validator` which will either use the object's own `IValidatable` implementation, or constructs another. This way, there is no need for casting objects back because the concepts remain separate.

Comment: Hmmm, the `Comparer`/`IComparable` solution sounds interesting but unfortunately it would probably involve changing too much existing code to be practical in my particular case. Thanks for the idea though, I may explore that a bit further...

Answer (score 1):

Implicit and explicit conversion operators are never evaluated for interfaces.  If you want to allow a reference of type `IValidatable` to be convertible to a reference of some type (which is hopefully that of the underlying object), then either `IValidatable` will have to include a property that returns the content [I would recommend avoiding the name `Object`] as a reference of type `System.Object`, or else have a generic method `T GetContentAs<T>()` that will try to return the content as a particular type.  Neither will provide public type safety, but that's to be expected when using a non-generic interface.

Alternatively, you could make a covariant interface `IValidatable<out T>` interface with a read-only `Content` property of type `T`.  One wouldn't be able to use the casting operator to extract the content from an `IValidatable<Foo>` to `Foo`, but one could simply use the `IValidatable<Foo>.Content` property.